# How was Carol Marcus able to be (successfully) beamed while moving?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter, star-trek-into-darkness

When Marcus was beaming his daughter on board she was running while it was happening.

How did she not die if you're supposed to stay still when you're energizing?

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe. There are multiple examples of people being successfully transported while in motion.